# Comparing array element to zero?

Tags: java, arrays, conditional-statements

Alright, so my goal is to complete the following assignment:

"Design and implement an application that determines and prints the number of odd, even, and zero digits in an integer  value  read from the keyboard.

SPECIFICATION OF PROMPTS, LABELS AND OUTPUT : Your code should not have any prompt at all. The input to this program  is a single integer . After the integer  is read, the output  consists of three lines. The first line consists of the number of odd  digits in the integer  followed by the label "odd digits". The second line consists of the number of even  digits in the integer  followed by the label "even digits". The third line consists of the number of zero  digits in the integer  followed by the label "zero digits". For example, if 173048 were read in, the output  would be:
3 odd digits
3 even digits
1 zero digits
SPECIFICATION OF NAMES: Your application class  should be called DigitAnalyst"

And the code I have produced is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DigitAnalyst{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String num = scan.next();
    int odd_count = 0;
    int even_count = 0;
    int zero_count = 0;
    //input an int as a string, and set counter variables

    int[] num_array = new int[num.length()];
    //ready a array so we can so we can parse it sanely
    for (int i =0; i < num.length(); i++)
    {
        num_array[i] = num.charAt(i);
    }//fill the array with the values in the initial  number using a loop

    for ( int i=0;i< num_array.length; i++)
    {
        if (num_array[i] % 2 ==0)
        {
            if (num_array[i] ==0 )//the hell is going on here?
            {
                zero_count++;
            }
            else if (num_array[i] != 0)
            {
                even_count++;
            }
        }
        else if (num_array[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            odd_count++;
        }
    }//use this loop to check each part of the array

    System.out.println(odd_count+ " odd digits");
    System.out.println(even_count+" even digits");
    System.out.println(zero_count+" zero digits");

}
```

}

And yet I keep getting the wrong output. More specifically, it returns the correct amount of odd numbers but it keeps counting 0 as an even and not as a zero.

I know where the problem is but I have no idea what is wrong, and I've spent a few hours on this. 
If someone could point me in the right direction I'd be ectstatic.

Comment: You might want to look at what `charAt()` actually returns, you're not comparing what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you encounter a problem that involves the manipulation of digits in an integer, the standard approach is to use an actual integer and the operator `%`, rather than strings. Instead of `scan.next()` use

```
int num = scan.nextInt();
```

And then you can do this:

```
do {
    int digit = num % 10;

    if ( digit == 0 ) {
        zero_count ++;
    } else if ( digit % 2 == 0 ) {
        even_count ++;
    } else {
        odd_count ++;
    }

    num /= 10;

} while ( num > 0 );
```

The idea is that when you divide a number by 10, the remainder is exactly the rightmost digit, and the quotient will have all the other digits. That's simply how the decimal system works.

In this method you get the digit directly without calling any method, and you don't need any arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the integer element with `num.charAt(i)` the ASCII value of the character is assigned and you get wrong results. In order to fix this, change

`num_array[i] = num.charAt(i);`

to

`num_array[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(num.charAt(i)));` 
or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some help here. First, `charAt()` returns the character at the index in the string, as a `char` data type. You're storing in an array of `ints`, which is assuming the numerical value of the character in the set, not the actual value.

Try this instead...

Change:

```
int[] num_array = new int[num.length()];
```

to:

```
char[] num_array = new char[num.length()];
```

and wrap all your `num_array[i]` references in your conditionals with:

```
Character.getNumericValue(num_array[i])
```

You should get your expected results.

```
Input = 12340
Output = 
2 odd digits
2 even digits
1 zero digits
```